# Questions about div and id?

Tags: html, css

Just a tutorial. Problem is {border: 3px solid yellow;}and my web page only one letter has the border with the solid yellow around it.

I have coded below:

```css
#cornholio {
        border: 3px solid yellow; 
        color: red;
        position: absolute;
        width: 10px;
        height:15px;
        top:375px;
        left:900px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="cornholio">Beavis & Butthead</div>
```

Comment: You set width & height, border is just around element with this size, the rest of text overflows.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Your `<div>` is only 10 pixels wide. One letter is all that fits. The rest is overflowing

Comment: you are seen rest of the text because of overflow. set 'overflow: hidden;' and the text will dissapear.

Comment: It all works exactly as one would expect.

Answer (score 0):

Here, the border is wrapping the entire text. As others said in comments, you were defining a fixed `height` and `width`, and therefore these two properties were not `auto` (size was not depending of content).

`auto` is the default value for `height` and `width`, so if you don't define them, it will work as you need:

**CSS:**

```
#cornholio {
    border: 3px solid yellow;
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:100px;
}
```

[Here is a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/chimos/vyz4b4jm/)